# Flutter : map dependencie crashes the app

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, google-maps-flutter

I'm trying to use google map with flutter so i'm using the dependencie "google_maps_flutter"
   version: "0.5.18"
The problem is when I add the line below (in my pubsec.yaml)-->

google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.16
[dependecies img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fuRG.png)

the app crashes.

Below is the picture of the error. I've tried to look what 15.0.1 and 16.0.1 were refering to but I have no idea.
[error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eYxZ.png)

Good to know :
When I add the above line the following code is automatically added.
[changes in the pubsec.lock file after adding above line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHmGP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error was in my dependencie (pubsec.yaml file) It seems location and google_maps_flutter aren't compatible. Either I had to remove one to make the other work.

Edit :

The plugin "geocoder: ^0.1.2" does work. I can successfully display location (lat & long) from typing addresses or by passing lat & long as parameters.
geocoder docs : https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder